MOK with VMware Workstation modules vmmon and vmnet with Secure Boot
I'm using VMware Workstation Pro 17. I'm trying to register modules with MOK for vmmon and vmnet. Apparently how you register them so they work with secure boot has changed since Unbuntu 22.04.
I am using Zorin 17 (basically the same as Ubuntu 22.04). The fixes I have tried seem to be outdated. Can someone walk me through this? Many thanks for any help.

